# Why are there sometimes 2 retweet_count fields in a tweet

Tags: twitter, tweets

Why are there sometimes 2 retweet_count fields in a tweet. How do I get the total number of retweets for a tweet?
Thanks

Comment: You don't really give a lot of info, but my guess is that you are getting confused with the `retweet_count` that belongs to the tweet, and if the tweet is a retweet there is another `retweet_count` which belongs to the original tweet. (The second one is the entity `retweeted_status`).

Comment: Hi Imzcig Yes that is what I was looking for. I went back to the API and my data and it makes sense. Can you post this as the answer so I can choose it and you get points?

Comment: Thanks @Cathy2cool. Done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really give a lot of info, but my guess is that you are getting confused with the `retweet_count` that belongs to the tweet, and if the tweet is a retweet there is another `retweet_count` which belongs to the original tweet. (The second one is the entity `retweeted_status`).

From twitter's documentation on [tweets' format](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets), `retweeted_status` is an object of type `Tweet`, thus it contains all the attributes of a tweet, and it has the following meaning.

> Users can amplify the broadcast of tweets authored by other users by
>   retweeting. Retweets can be distinguished from typical Tweets by the
>   existence of a retweeted_status attribute. This attribute contains a
>   representation of the original Tweet that was retweeted. Note that
>   retweets of retweets do not show representations of the intermediary
>   retweet, but only the original tweet. (Users can also unretweet a
>   retweet they created by deleting their retweet.)